# Is there anyway to trigger javascript in eventhandler with text input

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I have been studying XSS recently and I found a case.the html code is like this

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="foo" onblur="this.value"  x-webkit-speech/>
```

so I wonder if I can input something like `alert(1)` to make the onblur handler trigger the javascript..**is it possible?**

Comment: Input that where?

Comment: Did you see the html code i put in the question?

Comment: Yes. And how can you inject something in there? What part can you manipulate, to what extent?

Comment: sorry i just change the code for simplicity,basically what i meant is can you just input  javascript like alert() into the window  to trigger the onblur event.

Comment: No, `onblur="this.value"` is pointless but not a weakness that you can exploit. When it runs, it just evaluates the property to a string and throws it away. Also, you cannot inject an input value anyway, so you could only attack yourself ([which is much easier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS))

Comment: yeah i guessed that but i want to make sure.really thank you for your time and the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In javascript, "this" refers to the current element. Since the input onblur  event references the value of the element, the input will run whatever you put in it. However, unless this can be reflected through a url, this will be of no use.

Comment: Your answer submission of an old question bumped it up and made me accidentally answer it too. lol oh well..

Answer (score 0):

> so I wonder if I can input something like alert(1) to make the onblur
>   handler trigger the javascript..is it possible?

No it's not possible, you would need to evaluate the code you enter in the input box to execute it, as it's treated as a string not code.

You would need to do the following which, you should never need or want to do.

```html
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="alert('foo')" onblur="eval(this.value)" x-webkit-speech autofocus/>
```